# Plug two headphones on a MBP 2011 15"

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, ear-phones

Is there a way to use Mic/Line in as an output to plug a second set of earphones?

I gave a shot with JackPilot which is not compatible with macOS 10.12.3.

Answer (score 1):

No, however you could purchase a USB device that gives you a headphone output and use Audio MIDI Setup in macOS to aggregate outputs so it would output on both. Steps for that are here:

http://lifehacker.com/5933282/how-to-aggregate-and-use-multiple-audio-inputs-and-outputs-in-os-x

Alternatively, just buy a headphone splitter to split your one 3.5 mm jack into two. Like this:

[https://www.amazon.com/Belkin-Speaker-and-Headphone-Splitter/dp/B00009WQSR](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00009WQSR)

Comment: Any sources about your *No*?

Comment: I've been a mac admin for going on 20 years now. I know this was possible on some windows devices back in the day, but this was because there was custom driver and software support created for certain sound cards. I'd imagine there might be some tool or driver someone could create to do this, but I've never seen it before.